# Can't insert NULL value after db export

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

this is my problem.
i changed db position, first it was on an external server and i exported it on my local position (./SQLEXPRESS)
now i can't make insert record because it says that the record contain NULL id value. But it is correct because it is an auto-increment and i pass "0" or null for tell my db to insert a row (it is db.mytable.add(myrow) and it is the base behavior).
why now it tells me to pass a row with setted id?

this is the simply code

```
db.Company.Add(company);
db.SaveChanges();
```

and it give error on SaveChanges

i think it is a db owner problem

Comment: From what type of external server (full instance, Azure) using what tool (SSIS, other)?

Comment: i'm using EF, the serve is sql server 2008 r2. i used the tool inside sql managment studio, export database and i copied it inside my local

Answer (score 2):

You should check your DB again. Maybe the code is looking at the wrong DB, like `dbo.YourDB` instead of `NinoEmma.YourDB`. Because it can't find your DB, EF Code First will create one and the `id` column doesn't auto-increment anymore.